# How to perform a nested query in graphql using gatsby-source-prismic

Tags: graphql, gatsby, prismic.io

I'm just getting started with gatsby and graphql and I've started using prismic as a cms. I cannot figure out how to perform nested queries, avoiding overfetching. I don't even know if it would be possible or if it's more just me thinking of the problem in SQL terms.

I have two custom types on prismic which are related using a content relationship. These are `Productions` which have many `People` through a repeatable group of fields. The result I want is to have a page (the `home`) which shows the latest `production` with the list of `people` who starred in it, and another page with each person from `people` and all their roles in every `production`.

I managed to do this by fetching all the `people` in the `home` page and the required `production` and filtering the returned data in the frontend via javascript. However, I really feel that this way is not ideal since it requires to fetch all the people and not only the ones required for my page.

```
    allPrismicProduction(
      limit: 1
      sort: { fields: [last_publication_date], order: DESC }
    )  {
    edges {
      node {
        data {
          casting {
            ...castingData
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
    allPrismicPerson {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          data {
            name {
              text
            }
            photo {
              url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

const productions = data.allPrismicProduction.edges
const people = data.allPrismicPerson.edges
const sortedprods = []
productions.forEach(el => {
    let castings = el.node.data.casting.map(cast => cast.person.uid)
    castings.forEach(casting =>{
    people.filter(person => {
      if(castings.indexOf(person.node.uid) > -1){
        return person
      }
    sortedprods.push({
      production: el.node,
      people: relpeople,
    })
  })
})
```

So what I do is I fetch all `people` and then filter them according to the `uid`s found in the `production`s returned by the query.

I would like to know if it is possible, or otherwise what would be a better way to achieve this, how to limit overfetching by making it possible to only fetch the `people` who's `uid` is present in the `production`s given by the first part of the query.
Is this way of thinking compatible with graphql?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by looking around a bit more in the other issues of gatsby-source-prismic on github. 
The related-content node can be queried using the following structure:

```
{
  allPrismicMyContentType {
    edges {
      node {
        data {
          my_relations {
            relation {
              document {
                data {
```

where in data you can access all the properties of the type needed.

In this way one can do a single query to get all related content on prismic